# Disable Leaflet WMS getFeatureInfo popup while using the Measure tool

Tags: leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo, mapcontrol

I have a simple `Leaflet` map to which I've added two functionalities:

- **measure tool** using [leaflet.measure](https://github.com/jtreml/leaflet.measure) plugin;
- **WMS getFeatureInfo popup** using the [L.TileLayer.BetterWMS](https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938) plugin;

The default map behaviour in this context shows both popups - `measure popup` and `info popup`. 
Screenshot:

[image]

I have added the code to [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ralu_bur/kfzg4poe/2/).

So my question is:

*How can I prevent the info popup from showing up while using the measure tool?*

**Edit**

I managed to disable the popup by using

```
$( ".leaflet-control-measure" ).click(function() {
  map.off('click', layer.getFeatureInfo, layer);
});
```

but now I need to turn them back on. I tried using jQuery `toggle()`, but something weird happens to the measure button.

```
$(".leaflet-control-measure").toggle(function() {
  map.off('click', layer.getFeatureInfo, layer);
 } , function() {
  map.on('click', layer.getFeatureInfo, layer);
});
```

Comment: `Leaflet.TileLayer.BetterWMS` is not a well-known Leaflet plugin. Where did you get it? The solution will depend on its implementation of the popups.

Comment: I have added the url for the `L.TileLayer.BetterWMS` plugin in my question. I got it from GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IvanSanchez's [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/232806/57676) got me on the right track.
The `L.TileLayer.BetterWMS` plugin uses the following methods to enable/disable the `getFeatureInfo` popups:

```
  onAdd: function (map) {
    ...
    map.on('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
  },

  onRemove: function (map) {
    ...
    map.off('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
  },
```

So I had to toggle between these two states. I managed to do that by binding a click event on the `leaflet-control-measure` button:

```
$(".leaflet-control-measure").click(function() {
  var oddClick = $(this).data("oddClick");
  $(this).data("oddClick", !oddClick);
  if (!oddClick) {
    map.off('click', layer.getFeatureInfo, layer);
  } else {
    map.on('click', layer.getFeatureInfo, layer);
  }
});
```

I used the [`oddClick` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487348/why-arent-these-two-functions-toggling-on-click-event) because apparently the jQuery `.toggle()` has been deprecated.

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ralu_bur/kfzg4poe/4/).

Answer (score 1):

Given the implementation of `L.TileLayer.BetterWMS` that you are using, you should be able to disable the `getFeatureInfo` clicks with something like:

```
map.off('click', wmsLayer.getFeatureInfo, wmsLayer);
```

...and enable them back again with `.on`. You should be doing this whenever a measurement starts/ends.

Comment: They simply detach the event handlers that BetterWMS [attaches to the map](https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938#file-l-tilelayer-betterwms-js-L7). Ideally, BetterWMS should have the ability to toggle this functionality on and off, instead of being always-on and relying on this kind of hack.

Comment: You're right! Now that I look at `L.TileLayer.BetterWMS`, I can see the `onAdd` and `onRemove` methods. I have disabled the popups with a click on measure button, but now the tricky part is to enable them back on. Please see my edited post.

Comment: I have found the solution based on your approach.. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ralu_bur/kfzg4poe/3/). Should I edit your answer and mark it as accepted or should I add a new answer and include the `toggle oddclick` part?

Comment: As you wish. Personally I'd prefer if you added your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the css to `display: none;` so that the tooltips won't show eg:

```
.leaflet-measure-tooltip {
    font: 9px/1.25 "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: none;
}
.leaflet-measure-tooltip-total {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfzg4poe/1/)

**Edit**: Just realized you're looking to disable the WMS popups not the measure:
The attached jsfiddle in OP isn't showing a WMS service for me

Comment: I attribute my poor reading to not finishing my morning's coffee! In your JSFiddle I can't see the WMS? I think you can accomplish this using javascript and on click events, and change the css properties to `none` or `display`

Comment: I can see that the jsFiddle I provided is quite buggy, sometimes it loads the WMS layer, sometimes it doesn't (without changing anything in the code). When it DOES work, I can also see the getFeatureInfo requests in the Network in Dev Tools. Thanks for the javascript/css idea, I will try it.

Comment: I have edited my post, I tried using jQuery `toggle()`, `show/hide()`, and `display:none`, and while it hides/shows the currently open popup, when I click elsewhere on the map, other popups still appear.